# Protractor- need to slow down promise resolves

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

In testing my Angular App e2e, I have a promise that resolves to quickly and the element does not show(to be clear it does show outside of the test when clicking manually).

I used this code to slow down the promise resolves. It does successfully slow down the protractor test in everything else... but it does not slow down the promise resolves. Any suggestions?

```
origFn = browser.driver.controlFlow().execute;

browser.driver.controlFlow().execute = function() {
  var args;
  args = arguments;
  origFn.call(browser.driver.controlFlow(), function() {
    return protractor.promise.delayed(100);
  });   
  return origFn.apply(browser.driver.controlFlow(), args);
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to test if some loading indicator appears or what?

Comment: Sort of....I have a banner for loading. When a promise is resolved, the banner is dismissed. In this case the banner does not show because everything is so quick.

Comment: To slow down without any explicit condition i use `browser.sleep()` function. Though its not a standard coding technique, but it does the job. Hope it helps.

Comment: No, this will not slow down a promise resolve, which is what I need to slow down.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Protractor waits all $http calls to be resolved before executing next async Promise. If your issue in some animation slowness, you might want to use something like next code block to wait until element isDisplayed() or isPresent() or more complicated condition:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by...).isDisplayed();
}, timeout);
```

Comment: This is with mock data and the issue is animation quickness...to quick because mock data is quick.